# Python Soap Zeep - Duplicating Results

Tags: python, zeep

This has been tripping me up all day. I'm trying to pull contents from a SOAP server via Zeep, but my results are duplicating each row. My issue seems to come up when I try to pull in the Lat/Long. What am I missing?

```
     {
       'stationID': '1',
        'Country': 'United States',
        'Port': [
            {
                'portNumber': '1',
                'stationName': ABC',
                'Geo': {
                    'Lat': '34',
                    'Long': '-119'
                },
            }
        ],
        'Pricing': [
            {
                'minPrice': 0.0,
     'maxPrice': 0.0
            }
        ],
        'numPorts': 1,
    },
    {
        'stationID': '2,
        'Country': 'United States',
        'Port': [
            {
                'portNumber': '1',
                'stationName': 'DEF,
                'Geo': {
                    'Lat': '35',
                    'Long': '-120'
                },
            }
        ],
        'Pricing': [
            {
                'minPrice': 0.0,
                'maxPrice': 0.0,
            }
        ],
        'numPorts': 1,
    }
```

For right now, I would like to pull stationID, stationName, Lat, and Long.

```
from zeep import Client
from zeep.wsse.username import UsernameToken

s = []
x = []
for (i, d) in enumerate(stationData.stationData):
    row_station = [str(d.stationID)]
    for (p, pt) in enumerate(d.PortID):
        port = [str(pt.stationName)]
        for (g, ge) in enumerate(pt.Geo):
            c = stationData.stationData[i].PortID[p].Geo
            x = [str(c.Lat), str(c.Long)]
            s.append(row_station)
            s.extend(port)
            s.extend(x)
```

EDIT: Trying to make the formatting of the below tables more readable.

```
Current Output
|StationID  | stationName | Lat| Long|
|:--------- | :-----------|:---|:----|
|1          | ABC         | 34 | -119|
|1          | ABC         | 34 | -119|
|2          | DEF         | 35 | -120|
|2          | DEF         | 35 | -120|

Desired Output
|StationID  | stationName | Lat| Long|
|:--------- | :-----------|:---|:----|
|1          | ABC         | 34 | -119|
|2          | DEF         | 35 | -120|
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any SOAP here

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
        for (g, ge) in enumerate(pt.Geo):
```

The above line wasn't necessary.

```
for (i, d) in enumerate(stationData.stationData):
    row_station = [str(d.stationID)]
    for (p, pt) in enumerate(d.PortID):
        port = [str(pt.stationName)]
        c = stationData.stationData[i].PortID[p].Geo
        x = [str(c.Lat), str(c.Long)]
        s.append(row_station)
        s.extend(port)
        s.extend(x)
```